# create Laravel package without running artisan on terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a laravel project (almost completed). I developed most of my dependencies on ping pong modules and admin pulgins - https://sky.pingpong-labs.com. My challenge is having to plug other modules "on the fly" - at run-time. I don't like the idea of running artisan. Is there any way I can create a version on my own ping pong modules without running artisan?
Or better still, is there anyway of running artisan with my php codes and not on terminal?

Ok, I found something, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code, so I did this:

```
Artisan::call('module:make',['name'=>'testModule']);
```

but I got error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'.

Any one with an idea?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code syntax wise. The error you are receiving must be triggered at some other point; check the stack trace.